# Transform and lambda with lists behaving differently that transform with tuples or dict. Is it expected? Why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, window-functions

While trying to apply pandas `transform` to return multiple values (the objective is to emulate multiple window functions aggregations on a given group), I noticed that when using the list construct the results are different from expected.

Specifically, instead of returning for each row the sum, the standard deviation and the average, it explodes the result vertically.

If one uses dictionary or tuples to wrap the aggregations, it doesn't explode the results vertically and for each row it display the sum, the standard deviation and the average (result wanted).

Below an example of the behavior explained above.

Why the behavior with list is different from the one with tuples and dictionaries?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1], "amount": [387885, 302749, 293763]})

# Line below returns 3 rows (one containing the sum, the second the standard deviation, and 3rd the average
df.groupby("id")[["amount"]].transform(lambda x: [x.sum(), np.std(x), np.mean(x)])

# The line below returns (984397, 42410.47770958912, 328132.3333333333) on each row
df.groupby("id")[["amount"]].transform(lambda x: (x.sum(), np.std(x), np.mean(x)))

# The line below return on {"sum": 984397, "std": 42410.47770958912, "avg": 328132.3333333333} on each row
df.groupby("id")[["amount"]].transform(lambda x: {"sum": x.sum(), "std": np.std(x), "avg": np.mean(x)})
```

Versions used to replicate the results: Python 3.7.3 Pandas 1.0.3 and Numpy 1.16.2

Comment: This is a coincidence with the fact that you used a length three dataframe and three stats to return from your `lambda`.  Try increasing your dataframe's length to four.  What happens is that `transform` looks to see what is returned from the callable and if the length matches the length of the group it assumes to return that as separate values for each element of the group.  Otherwise, it treats it like a scalar broadcast for every element of the group.  I would highly advise against this as you can seriously break things.  Rephrase your question to how to achieve a desired result.

Comment: @piRSquared as you rightly suggested, I tried by adding another row with id=1 and with the list option it does not explode the results anymore as you expected. Why the behavior of list is different from the tuple one though? Aren't they the same length? On a relative note, your comment is close to be an answer and if put as one with the additional explanation of the different tuple behiavour, happy to accept it.

Comment: The desired result is to not explode the results in case the amount of aggregations (in the example 3) is equal to the group size. But the question more than the desired result was to understand why with lists it behaves differently than other built-in collections like dict and tuples.